# Laravel 5 Joining One To Many Eloquent Models With AND Conditions

Tags: laravel

Am developing an HR system using Laravel 5.I have three tables which are leave_applications with a foreign key employee_id,employees table with a foreign key department_id and departments table.Now i want to get only leave applications based on or using department id.How do i do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have used a hasManyThrough relationship such that department has many leave applications through employees table and it is working. But i have another problem that i am not able to get that leave type name using a foreign key leave_type_id which is on the leave_applications table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, it sounds like Department hasMany Employees, and Employee hasMany LeaveApplications. With this setup, you can create another relationship: Department hasMany LeaveApplications Through Employees.

```
class Department extends Model {
    public function employees() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Employee');
    }

    public function leaveApplications() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\LeaveApplication', 'App\Employee');
    }
}
```

Now you can get all the leave applications directly from the department:

```
$department = Department::find($id);
$leaveApplications = $department->leaveApplications;
```

### Edit

*answering question from comments*

From your field descriptions, your LeaveApplication belongsTo LeaveType, so your model should look like:

```
class LeaveApplication extends Model {
    public function leaveType() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\LeaveType');
    }
}
```

Now you can access the LeaveType name from the LeaveApplication:

```
// add in eager loading to avoid N+1 queries
$department = Department::with('leaveApplications.leaveType')->find($id);
$leaveApplications = $department->leaveApplications;

foreach($leaveApplications as $leaveApplication) {
    print_r($leaveApplication->leaveType->name);
}
```

You can read more about Laravel relationships in the documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships).

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked perfectly with a blink of an eye.

Comment: Based on that relationship. The leave_applications table has a foreign key names leave_type_id which references id on leave_types table,now i want to append that on the above codes and get the name of that particular leave type.How do i do that.I have tried to use join with no success Thanks again

Comment: That worked fine,but i also got the same data just using the methods in the LeaveApplication model using dynamic properties from the controller.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the model and relation setup correctly:

```
$leave_applications = [];
Department::with(['employees.leave_applications' => function ($q) use (&$leave_applications) {
        $leave_applications = $q->get()->unique();
    }])
    ->findOrFail($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a model class for your `leave_applications` table and put scopes and relations in that model:

```
class LeaveApplication extends Model
{
    public function scopeOfDepartment($query, $department)
    {
        return $query->where('department_id', '=', $department);
    }

    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee');
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$leaveApplications = LeaveApplication::ofDepartment($departmentId)->get();

foreach ($leaveApplications as $application) {
    $employee = $application->employee;
}
```

Comment: According to the post, leave_applications has the employee_id, not the department_id.